# Inline If in Javascript to manipulate CSS code

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

Im trying to hide the calendar button if the page width is smaller than X pixels. There seems to be an incorrect syntax issue but I cant find out what I am doing wrong. Here is the code;

```
'calendars' : {
                    label : Dictionary.Calendar.AddCalendars,
                    icon : 'fa-calendar',
                    showText : false,
                    css : (($('.ak-page').width() < 500px ) ? 'col-xs-hide' : ''),
```

there are more properties below css, Im not going to include them here because I know the problem is at the line where I define 'css' property.

Comment: CSS is not JavaScript you cannot include JavaScript in CSS.  If you want to do this then generate your CSS dynamically from JavaScript, but you cannot embedded any script into CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`500px` is invalid JavaScript syntax.

Since jQuery's `width()` method returns the number of pixels as an integer, I think you mean:

```
css : (($('.ak-page').width() < 500 ) ? 'col-xs-hide' : '')
```

Or, if you can support [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), you can achieve this more reliably by checking the width of the screen, not the width of an arbitary element in your DOM:

```
css : (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 499px)').matches ? 'col-xs-hide' : '')
```

Comment: thanks man, I was trying to figure out what I was missing past hour, lol I can't believe that was the problem, I feel dumb